# Linklist Error Next Method?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;

        InitializeComponent();
        llname.AddLast("22");
        llname = llname.Next;
```

---

Error   1   'System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList' does not contain a definition for 'Next' and no extension method 'Next' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) D:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\SaveShared\DigALL\Form1.cs  38  29  MoodigX

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LinkedList<T>` doesn't have a next, but [`LinkedListNode<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4t9w6be.aspx) does.

```
 LinkedListNode<string> node = llname.AddLast("22");
 LinkedListNode<string> next = node.Next;
```